# Does groovy script support PowerShell syntax?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Does groovy script support PowerShell syntax? 
I have a PowerShell script that I would like to use in Jenkins pipeline. I was not able to find any PowerShell module under "Generate Pipeline Script".

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. PowerShell is a completely different scripting language than Groovy. You can exeucte your PowerShell script through Groovy though if you have a PowerShell interpretor available and Jenkins Pipeline Scripts allow to call it.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what you want to do. If you have an existing build script you want to translate into Jenkins pipeline, you would normally want to translate to Jenkinsfile-style groovy. However if you have a script to want to call, there is a [standard step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#powershell-powershell-script) to do that to do that. It is important to realise that this comes up as a single step wrt jenkins, but it might be what you want to do. As said, all depends.

Answer (score 0):

These answers are slightly confusing based on the question.

Can you run PowerShell in a Jenkins pipeline?  Absolutely

Are their caveats and weird catches to get Groovy to interpolate you script correctly?  Yes!

I think you can only run PowerShell on a Windows based Jenkins host or build node (even though you can run pwsh on all *nix machines).  To do this is you just call `powershell` instead of `sh` in the pipeline step.

```
powershell """
           Write-Host "PowerShell stuff in the pipeline"
           Write-Host "Because escaping vars can get gnarly I do this..."
           Set-Variable -Name "LonghandVar" -Value "Some Value"
"""
```